# when one column null then get data from other column

Tags: sql

hope you can help. Not showing the whole query because I don't think   its required but want to try and get the query to see there is a null value in 'street' so then look in 'free address' and put the result in there. I'm guessing it involves a case expression or concat

Current Result

```
SELECT

IdNum
street
free address

from ID


IdNum          street                  free address
  1          stack over flow               null
  2             null                   stack exchange
  3           downing street               null
```

Required Result - note free address column doesn't need to be on display,  just for purpose of demonstration.

```
 IdNum          street                    free address
   1         stack over flow                  null
   2         stack exchange                stack exchange
   3         downing street                   null
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Isnull(street,freeaddress) will work

Answer (score 2):

The `COALESCE()` function does this:

```
SELECT IdNum,
       COALESCE(street, free_address) as street,
       free_address
FROM ID;
```

Note:  `ID` is a strange name for a table and `free address` isn't a valid column name (because of the space).

`COALESCE()` is an ANSI standard function available in basically all databases.

Comment: many thanks to everyone who contributed to this, I was totally over thinking it !

Comment: The best way to thank is to accept the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COALESCE()` function, which can replace a `NULL` value with an alternative you choose:

```
SELECT IdNum, COALESCE(street, `free address`) AS street, `free address`
FROM ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE`, `COALESCE` or (in SQL-Server) `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT IdNum,
       CASE WHEN street IS NULL THEN free_address ELSE street END as street,
       free_address
FROM ID;

SELECT IdNum,
       COALESCE(street, free_address) as street,
       free_address
FROM ID;

SELECT IdNum,
       ISNULL(street, free_address) as street,
       free_address
FROM ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the database you're using you can use `ISNULL`, `NVL`, `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`.

Pick the right one here: [SQL NULL Functions at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following if working with SQL Server

```
Select [IdNum], 
Case 
When [street] Is Null AND [free address] Is Not Null 
Then [free address] else [street] END As 'street',
[free address]
from ID
```